# Condition inside if-statement not being satisfied, but is still executing

Tags: c++, if-statement

So mostly everything is starting to work with my vector class but I've run into one more small problem. Inside of my overloaded == operator, I have an if-statement that is executing even though it shouldn't be.

Here it is,

```
bool myStringVector::operator==(const myStringVector& data){
    std::cout << this->size() << " " << data.size() << std::endl;
    if(this->size() != data.size())
      return 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i){
      std::cout << *(base+i) << " " << *(data.base+i) << ";" << std::endl;
      if(*(base+i) != *(data.base+i)){
        std::cout << *(base+i) << " " << *(data.base+i) << ";" << std::endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }
    return 1;
  }
```

and main...

```
myStringVector v1 {"a", "b", "c"};
//std::cout << v1[0] << v1[1] << v1[2] << std::endl;
myStringVector v2 = v1;
//std::cout << "here?\n";
//std::cout << v1[0] << v1[1] << v1[2] << std::endl;
//std::cout << v2[0] << v2[1] << v2[2] << std::endl;
assert(v1 == v2);
std::cout << "Passed copy ctor" << std::endl;
```

I added some cout statements to check whether or not the values are correct or not. I also check the size of both objects. When I run the program, heres what I get...

3 3

a a;

a a;

Assertion failed: v1 == v2, file myCodeTres.cpp, line 60

Im pretty sure my logic is right here. Both *base and *(data.base) contain 'a', so they should be equal. And I wrote this function to only return with 0 if they are not equal. Inside of these vectors are myString objects. I believe I've fixed the issues I had with my string class in response to my last question. But if you believe my custom string class is still a part of the problem let me know.

If you need me to upload any other functions for my vector class let me know! I wanted to try and keep this post as short as possible.

Comment: You can use `base[i]` instead of `*(base+i)`

Comment: what is the type of `base`? Is it an array of `std::string`, or of `char*` ? I'm guessing your problem is you're comparing char* _pointers_ or something similar to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing C strings (`const char*`) with each other. This does not compare the contents of the strings, but rather the locations in memory where they are stored. You can use `strcmp` to compare them as follows:

```
bool myStringVector::operator==(const myStringVector& data){
    if(size() != data.size())
      return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i){
      if(strcmp(base[i], data.base[i]))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment update:

It looks like you're not using `const char*` but rather your own string type `myString`. You then simply need to implement `bool myString::operator==(const myString& s) const;` and then you can use the below simpler implementation:

```
bool myStringVector::operator==(const myStringVector& data) {
   return std::equal(&base[0],      &base[size()], 
                     &data.base[0], &data.base[data.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Okay I definitely believe this is the issue. Thanks for helping me see that. One more thing, I am getting a compiler error now that indicates the line with strcmp and highlights base[i]. It says "cannot convert 'myString' to 'const char*'. Would this be due to the operations that would've taken place in my copy constructor?

Comment: It then looks like you're not using `const char*` but rather your own type of string. You can implement `myString::operator==(const myString&) const;` for your string, and then you can simply use equality as above.